# Outlined TextInputLayout Not rendering properly

Tags: android, material-design, textfield, androidx

Using the new Material Design guidelines I am trying to create a textfield that is outlined.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="10dp">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The result has no outline or change in appearance. Android Studio does throw a Render Problem. 'Couldn't resolve resource @string/path_password_strike_through' . I have tried to rebuild and clean the project with no luck.

Any thoughts would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue, add this `app:passwordToggleDrawable="@string/your_string"` and an error while rendering `TextInputLayout` that says `Couldn't resolve resource @string/path_password_strike_through` is gone.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@string/your_string">
```